# How I can to scrape website where information loading through jquery?

Tags: python, parsing

I want to scrape from https://www.flashscore.com/football/england/premier-league-2012-2013/results/ results from all round , default we have from 28 to 38 , i need all round , when i click to 'show more match' in 'network' i have url = [https://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/tr_1_198_dYlOSQOD_81_2_2_en_1[1]](https://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/tr_1_198_dYlOSQOD_81_2_2_en_1%5B1%5D) , when i open - i have :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IntOX.png) HELP ME PLEASE!!!

p.s sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Hello @mickyfortysix, am assuming you are using python, if yes then why dont you try Selenium. Once you have pressed ```show more match``` until all the results are fetched, just simply take the source from browser and scrape it like you do normally.

Comment: Also, Scrapy is also good in python for dynamic webpages. Some useful links 

1) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scrape-content-from-dynamic-websites/

2) https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/web-scraping-using-beautiful-soup-and-selenium-for-dynamic-page-2f8ad15efe25

3) https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50785084.html